# IIS Load balancing

Tags: iis

Last week we deployed IIS websites under a Load balancer and web hosting path is replicated using DFS.
Now I see if I add a website in server 1, I also need to add it on server2.
Is there any way to have it replicated, like we add websites or do changes in bindings or anything, it also gets reflected on the other server?
Server 2019 on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WebDeploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) or [SharedConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/shared-configuration_264) to sync/mirror IIS sites.